# Switch all "href = (link)" with "onclick = (PythonScript(link)) "

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am working on a webscraper that scrapes a website, does some stuff to the body of the website, and outputs that into a new html file. One of the features would be to take any hyperlinks in the html file and instead run a script where the link would be an input for the script.

I want to go from this..

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Scraper</title>
</head>

<body>
<a href="/wiki/Mercury_poisoning" title="Mercury poisoning">
 mercury poisoning
</a>

</body>

</html>
```

To this....

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Scraper</title>
</head>

<body>
<a onclick ='pythonScript(/wiki/Mercury_poisoning)' href="#" title="Mercury poisoning">
 mercury poisoning
</a>

</body>

</html>
```

I did a lot of googling and I read about jQuery and ajax but do not know these tools and would prefer to do this in python. Is it possible to do this using File IO in python?

Comment: what would your `pythonScript(/wiki/Mercury_poisoning)` be performing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this using `BeautifulSoup`:

**PS:** You need to install `Beautifulsoup`: `pip install bs4`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs


html = '''<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Scraper</title>
</head>

<body>
<a href="/wiki/Mercury_poisoning" title="Mercury poisoning">
 mercury poisoning
</a>

</body>

</html>
'''

soup = bs(html, 'html.parser')
links = soup.find_all('a')
for link in links:
    actual_link = link['href']
    link['href'] = '#'
    link['onclick'] = 'pythonScript({})'.format(actual_link)
print(soup)
```

Output:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>Scraper</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" onclick="pythonScript(/wiki/Mercury_poisoning)" title="Mercury poisoning">
 mercury poisoning
</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**Bonus:**

You can also create a new HTML file like this:

```
with open('new_html_file.html', 'w') as out:
    out.write(str(soup))
```